# How to add section titles to group fields in content type input form used to create content?

Tags: 7, theming, forms

Is there a module or setting to provide a title to sections of the content type input form used to create content?

For example - a job application form would have sections:

Section Title: Your Details
- Name
- Address

Section Title: Previous Employment
- Employer etc

Section Title: Qualifications

Happy to consider writing a custom module to output HTML and CSS to do this but wondered if there was a module or setting.

I'm currently using display_suite to do some layout design of the form in-browser.

(I've done some research and have seen https://drupal.org/project/multistep module but I would prefer all the sections on one page at the moment, that module may be useful for something else, though. Also aware of https://drupal.org/project/field_group which I expect to use but not sure if it provides titling above the field group).

Answer (score 1):

[Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module is best solution. It will allow you titling above the field group.

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div wrappers.